# Imported configurable products

Tags: magento2, configurable-product, import, import-products

[image: Parent product variations]I have imported Configurable products
But It is showing like this
[image: Screenshot of product]

The parent product price and quantity is not imported only their variations price and quantity is imported
Can any suggest me why Is It shown Like this ???/

Comment: Have you done reindex after imported data?

Comment: yes  several times

Answer (score 0):

Configurable product have not Qty and Price they are related to his child products.
What are prices and qty of childs?

Comment: I have re edited the post and shared the screenshot for child variations and their prices

Comment: Are you sure about childs, they have different sizes than swatches which are we see in on configurable product.

Comment: Yes I am sure and have created the size as swatches in product attributes

Comment: Okay, give some details, how do you import products, show some peace of code or csv file. 

Screenshot looks fine in swatches part, but in price part is something strange - you are right.

Can you check in current store view (scope) are you have different prices for childs? In Some cases when imports complete it was applied to storeview/website instead of global scope.

Comment: You can share email I will mail you CSV